# Read several csv from another folder in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

my python file in which I work is contained in the following path '/Users/pycar/Documents/Srett/Python/',
In this same space I have a folder that contains 8 other folders that all contain a csv that I want to import via panda because it's a database, the problem is that most of the codes found do not work (It says that the file is named 'month' and that the 8 folders are named by the first 8 months of the year then it does not matter what the names of the csv inside.

I would like to make a loop that digs into 'month' and goes into each folder (so january february etc...) and import the csv that is contained inside (with a read.csv).

for a little more visibility tell you that the file my_python is my notebook and that it is in the same folder as month which contains what I gave you

my_python

month-> january -> jan.csv

month-> February -> feb.csv

month-> March -> mar.csv

month-> April -> apr.csv

month-> May -> may.csv

month-> June -> jun.csv

month-> july -> jul.csv

month-> August -> Aug.csv

How can i proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If catalog `month` and subcatalogs hold solely csv files of interest, you might use [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob). Please prepare following script in same catalog in which `month` catalog is present, run it and write if it does print all csv files you want to get:

```
import glob
for i in glob.glob('month/*/*.csv'):
    print(i)
```

Comment: it prints me the sub-files of the months so january february etc... with after effectively the csv them corresponding

Comment: it prints me the sub-files of the months so January February etc... with after effectively the csv them corresponding, it is roughly the following path: 'month\January\Jan.csv' that it prints me for all the months

Comment: @jer_card this is what is intended. You should be able to use these paths in `pandas.read_csv` (with 1 call for each file)

Comment: By taking your tip and tweaking the loop I succeeded I thank you very much!